# Notification setAutoCancel(true) doesn't work

Tags: android, notifications, click

I'm trying to show a notification that is removed when the user taps on it.
I'm using the `NotificationCompat` class to build my notification and I call `setAutoCancel(true)` on my builder. This is the piece of code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText("content");
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

The notification is correctly added but when I tap on it nothing happens! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The notification just stays there? What happens when you swipe it to dismiss it? What device and API version are you running?

Comment: I'm running on Galaxy Nexsus, API 4.2.2. The notification disappear if i swipe it, but if I simply tap it nothing happens.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Using setContentIntent should solve your problem:

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
```

In your example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText("content")
        .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Often you might want to direct the user to the relevant content and so might replace 'new Intent()' with something else.

I uploaded a [demo](https://github.com/snodnipper/press-delete-notification) to github.

Comment: Thanks. Though the user can still clear the notification away by swiping it.

Comment: I've found out that this works, but it can lead to a particular unexpected result: I also open the contentIntent seperately from the notification. This can auto cancel the sound of the notification (On moto g3 it does, on Google Pixel it doesn't).

Comment: This also closes the notification list. Would be even better if there was a way that doesn't close it.

Answer (score 31):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but I had the same problem with a different solution so I will share it here.

For me, I was using the same `NotificationCompat.Builder` object to create a notification which called `setOngoing(true)`. This was for an upload progress notification which should not be removed while working.

Anyways, after the task was complete, I called `setAutoCancel(true)` but the notification was still not swiping away. What I had to do also was call `setOngoing(false)`.

It seems pretty obvious now, but it might save someone else some time in the future.

Comment: What does `setOngoing` do?

Comment: It didn't work for me :-(