# Trying to clear android notification through SetAutoCancel(true)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I am opening an intent on clicking the notification. But the notification as such doesn't go away. I tried SetAutoCancel(true) and SetOngoing(false). What is missing or wrong here. How can I make the notification in the notification bar go away when clicking on it. I am not even able to manually swipe it to go away.

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification)
    .SetContentTitle("Smart Office")
    .SetContentText(message)
    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetOngoing(false);
var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did this [Notification setAutoCancel(true) doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033316/notification-setautocanceltrue-doesnt-work) answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, I set SetContentIntent(pendingIntent) and SetOngoing(false) as mentioned in the answer in the above comment. But doesn't work.

Comment: Did you want to cancel foreground notification or service? User is not allowed to swipe away a notification generated by an ongoing foreground service. You can cancel the foreground service by using the` stopService()`.